# How to send list of objects to WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-4.0, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

I'm building WCF service and I would like to accept List as a parameter to one of my method.

Here is my code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int InsertProducts(List<Product> products);
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(List<Product>))]
public class Product
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductId{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

When I run service it gives me an error.

This operation is not supported in the WCF, because it uses `NameSpace.Product[]`

Comment: You don't need [KnownType(typeof(List<Product>))]

Answer (score 5):

When sending a generic list over WCF we always create a class which has a property which is the list.

```
[ServiceContract] 
public interface IProductService 
{ 
    [OperationContract] 
    int InsertProducts(MyListofProducts products); 
 } 


[DataContract] 
public class  MyListofProducts
{

    [DataMember] 
    List<Product> Products { get; set; }

 }

[DataContract] 
public class Product 
{ 
    [DataMember] 
    public int ProductId{ get; set; } 

    [DataMember] 
    public string ProductName{ get; set; } 

    [DataMember] 
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you have suggested. and I'm getting the same error. I'm using the WCF Test Client, can it be the problem? Maybe it interface doesn't support the List?

Comment: There is another possible problem, that is that you have Products that contain Products. You could try with a sub product type of products

Comment: If I call service from console application I'm able to send List. It's only doesn't work properly with WCF Test Client

Comment: Then the difference is in the config file. Make sure that the confif settings are in the app.config of the test project.